# How to send email to all members of one team using workflow?

Tags: c#, email, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

In workflow, I created some entity and set it's owner to team. Now I want to send email to every member of that team.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easy if you could create an Exchange distribution list and then set the Default Queue's email address to that distribution list: [image: Send Workflow Email]